# Writing to a file with Windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file like that

```
Some text here, with a %var% .... and other text with the same %var%
```

Basically, I want to create another file and replace %var% with a variable of my choice. I'm using windows batch (.bat). The user enter the variable.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some variables in your batch file, something like this:

```
set var=text
set nextvar=moretext
```

Then you can export it to a file, choosing to include which variables you want, like this:

```
echo Some text here, with a %var% or %nextvar% >C:\file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

to complete Bali's answer, for requesting the user to enter the value of the variable..

read `HELP SET` and then try

```
SET /P var=Enter some text: 
ECHO Some text here, with a %var% >out.txt
ECHO ... and other text with the same %var% >>out.txt
```